# Continu increment and decrement value

Tags: flutter

I would like to know if there is a way to continuously increment or decrement a value as long as my fingering remains on the button.
whats method do use?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can easily do this using `GestureDetector` widget provided by flutter.

Basically, the idea is to use the `onLongPressStart`, `onLongPressEnd` of the `GestureDetector` and a `Timer.periodic` from the `dart:async` library to do this.

The `onLongPressStart` and `onLongPressEnd` are self explanatory, they are callbacks to when the long press event starts and ends.

The `Timer.periodic` is what we use to run continuously run some code for every duration, which we specify using `Duration(milliseconds: 100)` which means we are saying, `run my code continuously every 100ms till I cancel`

Here is the full working code.

```
import 'dart:async';

class TimerExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => TimerState();
}

class TimerState extends State<TimerExample> {
  int counter = 0;    // Create a counter to maintain the number
  Timer timer;        // Create a timer that we can use to cancel later

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onLongPressStart: (details) {
          // When the longpress starts, create a Timer.periodic and assign it to timer variable
          timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 100), (timer) {
            // Timer.periodic runs every 100 ms and updates the state
            setState(() {
              counter++;
            });
          });
        },
        onLongPressEnd: (details) {
          // when longpress ends, call timer.cancel to stop your timer
          timer.cancel();
        },
        child: Container(
          height: 50,
          width: 50,
          color: Colors.deepOrange,
          child: Text('$counter')),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad to have helped :) Do consider accepting my answer if it works for you.